# How to map an array of objects, to return an array of objects with new keys

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render array objects, but my code only renders one object and throws an error when I try to add multiple objects.

If I try to add another Question set, it throws the following error: Line 16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
  14 |     c: "Trump"
  15 |   },
> 16 |   {
     |   ^
  17 |     question: "Who is the president of America?",
  18 |     answers: {
  19 |       a: "Buhari",
```

code:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
questions =  [
{
  question: "Who is the president of America?",
  answers: {
    a: "Buhari",
    b: "Putin",
    c: "Trump"
  },

}         
];
this.state = {
    question : [],
};
}

handleQuestion(){ 
  this.setState({
  question: questions
});    
}
render(){    
  return (    
      <div className = "container">
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.handleQuestion()}>
        Show Question
      </button>   

      <ul>
        {this.state.question.map((data,i)=>(

            <li key={i}>{data.question}       
              <div>a : {data.answers.a}</div>
              <div>b : {data.answers.b}</div>
              <div>c : {data.answers.c}</div>
            </li>

          ))
         }
      </ul> 
   </div> 
 ); 
 }
 }

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the questions array in constructor correctly Either you have to use keywords like `const`, `var`, `let` to define them or you define it as a `class instane property`. Looking at your case, you should define it as a class instance property if you want to define it as a class member or otherwise you can declare it outside the class scope to as a global variable

```js
  class Question extends React.Component
      constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.questions =  [
          {
            question: "Who is the president of America?",
            answers: {
              a: "Buhari",
              b: "Putin",
              c: "Trump"
            },

          }         
          ];
          this.state = {
              question : [],
          };
      }

      handleQuestion(){ 
        this.setState({
        question: this.questions
      });    
      }
      render(){    
        return (    
            <div className = "container">
            <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.handleQuestion()}>
              Show Question
            </button>   

            <ul>
              {this.state.question.map((data,i)=>(

                  <li key={i}>{data.question}       
                    <div>a : {data.answers.a}</div>
                    <div>b : {data.answers.b}</div>
                    <div>c : {data.answers.c}</div>
                  </li>

                ))
               }
            </ul> 
         </div> 
       ); 
      }
   }

     export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default state inside the constructor itself.

```
this.state = {
question: [
   {
   question: "Who is the president of America?",
   answers: {
    a: "Buhari",
    b: "Putin",
    c: "Trump"
   }
]
}
```

if you want to keep it empty. You should use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure the object is existed before rendering